# Notify JS not working correctly on fixed elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, notifyjs

**Problem**: If I initiate notify JS on a fixed element the notification will behave as if the element was placed using absolute positioning.

**Code Reference**:

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 2vh;
    border: solid 2px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(".box").notify("Click me!",{position:"bottom center",className:"success"});
```

**JS Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/kwzL4999/

**Replication Instructions**: Scroll down a bit and click on the element to see the above problem in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is use a div with class for example `"notify"` inside your div with class `"Box"`

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="notify"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".notify").on("click",function(){
$(this).notify("Click me!",{position:"bottom center",className:"success"});
});
```

Example Jsfiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kwzL4999/1/)

Comment: I actually found a work-around on my own by altering the notify css rules with JS (To make the notification's position fixed) but this is a much cleaner and effective solution.